# Lyx: can I export LaTeX without the preamble?

Tags: lyx

I would like to export Latex from Lyx without the preamble. For example I would like to automatically remove all code before `\section{}` as well as `\end{document}`.  This is so that I can automatically include the `.tex` output file into a larger Latex document for which I already have the preamble the way I want it.

The reason I am doing things this way is that I have large tables of equations which get very confusing to edit directly in plain Latex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly possible at the moment it seems, there is an open feature request for this in the LyX bug tracker:

- [Ability to export separate preamble/content latex files for including in existing latex document](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7333)

But there is at least one workaround described there:

Create a dummy master LyX file, and include the other file(s) as child documents. When exporting the master file, each child document is created as a separate `.tex` file, without preamble.

Answer (score 0):

### The `subfiles` package as workaround

A simpler workaround would be using the `\subfile` command of the `subfiles` package, which automatically strips the document skeleton.

It's meant for making child documents compilable on their own, but by extension also fits this usecase.

### Using a parent/child pair for export without preamble.

It does not help, if the purpose is to export to latex for inclusion in a journal template, where loading extra packages isn't allowed. In this case a viable workaround is to create a file `main.lyx` with child document `child.lyx`, and export from `main.lyx` recursively, which produces a preamble-free `child.tex`.

### Automation as a script

This could also be easily automated as a script, by exploiting the straight-forward file-format of `.lyx` documents:

- Create a `.tmp.lyx` with the same `\begin_header ... \end_header` as `child.lyx` to ensure consistent export of styles and insets.
- Make its `\begin_body ... \end_body` contain only the child-document link.
- Export `.tmp.lyx` to `.tmp.tex`. This will create the desired `child.tex`.
- Remove the unnecessary `.tmp.*` files.

Comment: Re the subfiles variant: That does not seem to be how the subfiles package works.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the `standalone` package in the including document as a workaround

The `standalone` package redefines `\input` so that any preamble is ignored. Usage:

- Export your lyx document to tex normally.
- In the including document, put `\usepackage{standalone}` in the preamble.
- Load the exported tex document normally using `\input` or `\include`.
- The preamble of the included document will be ignored.

The packge also has an option to somehow use a sub-preamble (see the docs), but I haven't used this.

NB: There's a standalone *package* and a standalone *document class*. The package is for the including document and the document class *can*, but doesn't need to be used for the included document. In this answer, we only use the package.