# importing a portion of another tex file

Tags: lyx, chapters, preamble, import

I have several papers that have full preambles including cover pages, package include statements, etc. I am compiling the papers into one long book that has chapters and would like to import that papers as individual chapters. In order to do this (because the formatting of the book is different than the papers), I need to skip the preamble and start with the first section of each paper. Is there a way to import each one starting from a particular point in the tex file?

Let me describe the setup so it's a bit clearer: I have each paper that I created in LyX. The master document is a tex file provided to me that has all the appropriate formatting etc. That is, the master file is not a LyX file but a usual tex file which imports the individual chapters.

The reason I want to do this (instead of manually just removing the preamble) is in the event I make changes, I don't want to have to make changes to two files, I would like them to be synced.

Comment: `\include` just includes the whole file.  So you could move the common part to a file and make shell files both for the paper and for the book.

Comment: @Thruston: that's a good idea in principal, the issue is i use LyX as my editor most of the time and it automatically throws in a preamble. i suppose i could start using texstudio for everything but i like the WYSIWYG-esque nature of LyX.

Comment: Hmmm - looks complicated - https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/Multidoc

Comment: Will the `combine` package help you? http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf . Also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155739/lyx-can-i-export-latex-without-the-preamble

Comment: When you include a file in LyX, the master document's preamble is used. So I actually think it works exactly how you want. Did you test? Perhaps I misunderstood: go to Insert > File > LyX document, compile and test that the master's preamble was used. Then open the LyX document on its own and compile that. The child's preamble should be used (if not, then make sure that in the child .lyx file "Select default master document" is unchecked and then I'm sure the child's preamble is used.

Comment: @scottkosty: i just updated the question because i realize it was unclear. each paper was created in LyX. The master file is a regular tex file that has all the formatting, it imports individuals chapters.

Comment: @Alex ah I understand better now. Can you just import the master .tex file into LyX to create a .lyx file?

Comment: @scottkosty: it's possible, i haven't tried to mess with their master file because it uses their own class etc. when you import things into lyx i know it doesn't always come out exactly right so i've avoided this (i won't be able to spot a minor difference in the format but they will)

Comment: @Alex makes sense!